# angular2 checkbox ng-model not updated

Tags: angular, checkbox

I am trying a simple thing with Angular 2.0
I want a bind a model to an 'input checkbox', register the 'change' with a method, have the method executed when the checkbox state is changed and act based on the state of the model.
Everything works but, when the method linked with the change event is executed, the state of the model is the contrary of what I expect, i.e. is false when the checkbox is selected, is true when the checkbox is unselected.
Here is the code snippet;

```
<input value={{object.name}} type="checkbox" [(ng-model)]="object.selected" (change)="onChange(object.selected)">
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: First question on stackoverflow. Unable to paste an html snippet.

Comment: you can paste some raw code anyway

Comment: paste the code then selected and click on code icon

Comment: "'<input value={{object.name}} type="checkbox" [(ng-model)]="object.selected" (change)="onChange(object.selected)">'"

Comment: thanks, now the code is visible in the questios

Comment: It's simple: you edit your question, you paste the code, you select it, and you press Ctr-K (or hit the button of the toolbar for "code", which looks like this: `{}`.

Comment: I would recommend you to use ng-click insted ng-change so the onChange() will check if **was** True or False and change it

Answer (score 48):

As of angular2.beta8 this simple trick will do

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="object.selected" />
```

---

From Angular 4, must add the `name` attribute for this to bind.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="object.selected" name="element_name"/>
```

Comment: To use with *Angular4* I had to add "name" property to the input field.

Answer (score 28):

A way to do it without **ngModel**

```
<input
    id="{{fieldId}}"
    type="checkbox"
    [checked]="displayValue"
    (click)="setDisplayValue($event.target.checked)"
>
```

displayValue would be getter/setter
setDisplayValue() method will update the record and hence displayValue would be updated

Answer (score 16):

For me only works when I used `(ngModelChange)`:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       [(ngModel)]="object.selected" 
       (ngModelChange)="onChange(object.selected)">
```

If I use `(change)` or `(click)` the state is always contrary of what I expect, as you said

Comment: Tested as of Angular2 RC.4. Works perfectly.

Comment: Seems like the change event fires on changes in the DOM, and the ngModelChange fires when the object property changes. So when reading the object property on the change event, it has not yet been updated to the value of the DOM.

Answer (score 9):

I have implemented it like this: 
`<input #angularcb type="checkbox" (change)="angular = angularcb.checked" />`

You can also see more details and a live demo here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/input-controls-in-angular-2.0
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/input

Comment: and what if we have to generate checkboxes with `*ngFor` ?

Answer (score 7):

```html
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="object.selected == 'Y'" (ngModelChange)="object.selected=$event?'Y':'N'">
```

Comment: Some explanation could help others understand the solution better.

Comment: Thanks for help. Maybe i can explain. [NgModel] has a oneway binding with compare value, just to make checkbox appear as checked or unchecked. In (NgModelChange) you set value on model.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try and inspect the event object and just pull out the checked parameter

```
<input value={{object.name}} type="checkbox" [(ng-model)]="object.selected" (change)="onChange($event)">


 onChange(event) {
  var isChecked = event.currentTarget.checked;
 }
```

- seems like the event is being fired before the model gets a chance to update. It currently works fine for my select elements.

Comment: I noticed that the event gets fired before the model update as well.

Comment: just for reference https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2

Answer (score 4):

try this out

app.html

```
 <span *ngFor="#ca of classArray; #i=index">                                         
   <input type="checkbox"  id="{{ca.id}}" #cv [checked]=false                                       
    (change)="onChange(ca.id,cv.checked)">
         {{ca.class_name}},{{cv.checked}} <br>
 </span>
```

app.ts

```
 onChange(classId,flag){
        console.log(classId+" : "+flag);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="object.completed" (change)="object.completed = !objected.completed" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to include a name or the checkbox will not update and you will get an error on the console.

```
<label>Sign on<input type="checkbox" name='showLogin2' [(ngModel)]="model.ShowLogin" ></label>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Angular 2.x.x stable** :
easy way to know a checkbox is checked or not :

```
<input type="checkbox" #checkbox (change)="check(checkbox.checked)">
```

ts:

```
export class component{
  constructor() {}

  check(checked){

    if(checked){
      // checked
    }else{
      // not checked
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would be more robust to use (change)="check($event)", then the check() method has access to the checked property, as well as all other properties - plus you don't need to implement the #spy.

Answer (score 0):

just write checked in tag of input type  :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" checked />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="object.selected" />
<div>{{object | json}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="selectionChange($event.srcElement)">
```

**Change Event**

```
selectionChange(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    input.checked === true
      ? doSomethingIfTrue()
      : doSomethingIfFalse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input value={{object.name}} type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="object.selected" (change)="onChange(object.selected)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Form is just a set of key/value pairs. Name is the key which is used to identify/get/set the value of this control, so you need to specify the name of each control. When you set ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}" you tell angular to not include this input into the form. That's why your form is always valid. It is actually empty.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#options